# Code Golf: Piano

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The challenge

The shortest code by character count to output a part of a piano keyboard starting from input note in a given length.

Input will be composed of a note (`[ACDFG]#|[A-G]`) to start printing the keyboard from and a positive number representing length of keys to print including the first note.

The first key should be printed in full - if it has a left sharp key, it will be cut, same for when the start key is sharp, the left key will be cut as well.

A Sharp key is not counted, only white keys.

### Test cases

```
Input
    C 14
Output
    |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
    |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
    |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
    |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
    |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
```

---

```
Input
    D# 1
Output
    ###   |
    ###   |
    ###   |
    ###   |
    ###   |
     |    |
     |    |
     |    |
    _|____|
```

---

```
Input
    A 7
Output
    ##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
    ##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
    ##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
    ##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
    ##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
```

Code count includes input/output (i.e full program).

Comment: So it doesn't count sharp keys for displaying them, but it can start on a sharp key?

Comment: `[A-G]#*`? Does this mean we need to handle, say, `B#####` as `E`?

Comment: For the count of keys, define "key". Why is the example "C 14" printing 24 keys?

Comment: What Guffa said. I'd rather see a question which took the count in semitones.

Comment: @Anon. & @Guffa - Sorry, my bad at both.

Comment: "I'd rather see a question which took the count in semitones" Then the question will get much harder...

Comment: Beware of the special case where the starting note is a sharp note and the count is one. Perhaps you should add that as a test case, LiraNuna.

Comment: @LiraNuna: Wait, perhaps there is no special case there. I was thinking of counting also black keys, then a single black key would show half white keys on both sides...

Comment: OK, now that we got C and C# solutions, we need B, D and F#.

Comment: echo "Cannot play piano nor read tunes" - there, in 37 characters including whitespace!!! :D

Comment: @Austin Kelley Way, do you know J?

Comment: Next code golf: Implement a MIDI interface for these pianos.

Comment: No, though I probably could write it.

Comment: Please don't add 'summery of answers', looking at the answer list should be sufficient...

Comment: Here I am back to my old tricks again. Dear close voters: I agree that code golf questions are contests, not questions. None-the-less, this topic has been discussed at length on meta and the belongs on SO side has a solid consensus: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/so-weekly-code-golf . SO let it go. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions .

Comment: dmckee: Instead of arguing, I suggest to just let them close - I'm sure people will reopen it in less than a minute.

Comment: Open fire all opening batteries! don't let this hole in their defenses get closed! ;)

Comment: Dear closers, I salute you for managing to close this challenge after 3 days. We got it to reopen in 5 minutes. That alone should tell you something - the community likes and accepts this kind of questions, whether you like it or not. If you don't, however, please add code-golf to your list of ignored tags.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## GolfScript - 80 Characters

Fits in one line of #SO without the scroll bar :)

```
' ':s/~~5*\(7&5*\,.4*@+):k;+):c;9,{5<'#'9**' | '4*+3/4<.1>+c*s.+*k>c<n+}%)s/'_'*
```

**GolfScript - 81 Characters**

```
' ': /((7&\,.4*@5*+:k;\~~5*+):c;9,{5<'#'9**' | '4*+3/4<.1>+c*  +*k)>c<n+}%) /'_'*
```

Nicely formatted version (27 x 3)

```
' ': /((7&\,.4*@5*+:k;\~~5*
+):c;9,{5<'#'9**' | '4*+3/4
<.1>+9*  +*k)>c<n+}%) /'_'*
```

**GolfScript - 82 Characters**

```
' '/((7&\,.4*@5*+:k;\~~5*+):c;9,{5<3*'###  '*' |   '4*+20<.5>+c*k)>c<n+}%)' '/'_'*
```

**GolfScript - 85 Characters**

```
' '/((7&\,.4*@5*+:k;\~~5*+):c;9,{.5<3*'###  '*' _'1/@8=='|'1$3*++4*+20<.5>+c*k)>c<n}%
```

Nicely formatted version (17 x 5)

```
' '/((7&\,.4*@5*+
:k;\~~5*+):c;9,{.
5<3*'###  '*' _'1
/@8=='|'1$3*++4*+
20<.5>+c*k)>c<n}%
```

**GolfScript - 94 Characters**

```
' ': /~~5*:c;(7&5*:^;,:&;['###  '3*' |   '+.5>+c*1>{^4&*+>&c+)<n}:f~]5*'   _'1/{'|'\4*+7*c*f}%
```

**GolfScript - 98 Characters**

```
' ': /~~5*:c;(7&5*:^;,:&;['###  '3*' |   '+.5>+c*^4&*+:^)>&c+):&<n]5*[   '_']{['|'\4*+7*c*^>&<n]}%
```

**GolfScript - 101 Characters**

```
' ': /~~5*:c;(7&5*:^;,:&;['###  '3*' |   '+.5>+c*^4&*+)>&c+)<n]5*[   '_']{['|'\4*+7*c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]}%
```

**GolfScript - 109 Characters**

```
' ': /~~5*:c;(7&5*:^;,:&;['##''  ###'.'   | '++.'  #'+++c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]5*[   '_']{['|'\4*+7*c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]}%
```

**GolfScript - 120 Characters**

```
' '/~~5*:c;(7&5*:^;,:&;['##''  ###'.'   | '++.'  #'+++c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]5*['|    '7*c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]3*'|____'7*c*^4&*+>&c+)<
```

**GolfScript - 127 Characters**

```
' '/~~5*:c;(7&5*:^;,:&;['##  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   #'c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]5*['|    '7*c*^4&*+>&c+)<n]3*'|____'7*c*^4&*+>&c+)<

$ echo -n C 14 | ruby golfscript.rb piano.gs 
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
$ echo -n D# 1| ruby golfscript.rb piano.gs 
###   |
###   |
###   |
###   |
###   |
 |    |
 |    |
 |    |
_|____|
$ echo -n A 7| ruby golfscript.rb piano.gs 
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
```

Comment: I was about to submit my first golfscript entry for another challenge (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104556/code-golf-0-to-1-and-1-to-0-closed), but it got closed :-(

Comment: I wish they taught golfscript in school. I want my money back.

Comment: Nice. I'll post my solution in PianoScript later. It's only 6 characters. :-)

Answer (score 112):

### Perl, 133 (129) chars

Perl, <strike>167</strike> <strike>160</strike> <strike>156</strike> <strike>147</strike> <strike>142</strike> <strike>133</strike> D'oh! <strike>147</strike> <strike>144</strike> <strike>137</strike> <strike>134</strike> 133 chars

```
    $_=shift;die grep{5>$n?y/*/#/:y/#*/ |/;$n++-8||y/ /_/}
    @Q=(substr(("*#  #".("*#  #*#   |   #")x2)x9,
    4*/#/+(7&ord)*5,1+/#/+5*pop).$/)x9
```

Here's a 129 char solution, borrowing several ideas from molf's Ruby solution:

```
    ($_,$c)=@ARGV;$j=($k=/#/)+ord;
    for$n(0..8){print$/,substr+(join'',map{8-$n?5>$n&&$_%7%4?"###  "
    :" |   ":"_|___"}$j..$j+$c),!$k,-3}
```

and with help from the [Acme::AsciiArtinator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Acme::AsciiArtinator):

```
                sub init_piano{$S=$";$H='#';
                (                            $
               T                              ,$P,$U)=qw(
              T                                          |
             _                                            |
            /                                              )
           ;                                                $
          d             =$T.$H.$S.$S;$t                     =
         $             d               .                   $H
        .              $               d                  . $
       S               .$P.$S.$S.$S.$H;$                t=  $
      d.$H.$t.$t;};$_=shift;-/-/;&init_piano();$Z=/#/;-/|   |
      |                                                 |   |
      |                    YAMAHA                       |  /
      ;die grep{4>$n++?y/T/#/:y/#T/ |/;$n-8||y/ /_/;}@q=(m{
     // // /// // /// // /// // /// // /// // /// // /// /   
    // // /// // /// // /// // /// // /// // /// // /// /
   }                                                   .
   substr(${t}x(9),4*${Z}+(7&ord)*5,1+$Z+5*pop).$/)x(8)
          ;   '                            \   /
           | |                              | |
           /_\                              /';
```

Comment: Hahaha, awesome. Is that a Steinway, Yamaha, Young Chang?

Comment: I'm going to bookmark this to show to people who don't get the "monkey" joke.

Comment: @Steve - Let's make it a Yamaha

Comment: @mobrule, do you hate grep? why do you want it to die? :(

Comment: Golfscript * 1.3 would be 105 :)

Answer (score 34):

### Ruby - 125 chars

<strike>146</strike> <strike>144</strike> <strike>140</strike> <strike>137</strike> <strike>134</strike> <strike>126</strike> 125 chars

```
a,n=$*;h=a[1]?0:1;s=a[0]-h+1
9.times{|t|puts (s..s+n.to_i).map{|i|i%7%4<1||t>4?" |   ":"###  "
}.join[h..-4].tr t>7?" ":n,"_"}
```

(The second newline is not necessary and added only to avoid a scrollbar on SO. Semi-colons can be replaced by newlines if desired.)

The **Ruby 1.9** version is different but of equal length (replacing `a[0]` by `a.ord` and `"_"` by `?_`):

```
a,n=$*;h=a[1]?0:1;s=a.ord-h+1
9.times{|t|puts (s..s+n.to_i).map{|i|i%7%4<1||t>4?" |   ":"###  "
}.join[h..-4].tr t>7?" ":n,?_}
```

Call with

```
$ ruby piano.rb C 14
```

Comment: Hey VIM counts 138 chars on the first one?!?

Comment: a,n=gets.split;... does the same job, -3 chars

Comment: You could even replace "gets.split" by "$*" and give the input on the command line, -8 chars

Comment: Change `i%7%4<1||t>4?"_|___":"###__"` to `i%7%4&&t<5?"###__":"_|___"` and save 2 chars. I love that `%7%4` idiom

Comment: You can save 2 additional chars by replacing `"_"` by `?_` and removing the parentheses around the call to `tr` at the end (replacing the first parenthesis by a space).

Comment: @hurikhan77: awesome change! @mobrule: unfortunately (in this case) `0` is truthy in Ruby, so that won't work. @JRL: `?_` is a Fixnum (char code), and not a string in Ruby 1.8, but it does work in 1.9! Thanks!

Comment: So we are down to the shortest solution, eh? Ruby rulez! :-D

Comment: My ruby answer is up if you guys like to take a look if I've missed anything :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202897/code-golf-piano/2220265#2220265

Answer (score 29):

## **LilyPond, 285 <strike>288</strike> <strike>291</strike> <strike>310</strike> <strike>315</strike> <strike>330</strike> <strike>333</strike> <strike>340</strike> <strike>350</strike> characters**

In keeping with the music theme, here's a solution in a language designed for typesetting music scores, LilyPond:

```
x=#ly:string-substitute
u=#(x"*""###  ""|   *** |   ** ")t=#(x"###"" | "u)q=#read-char
z=#(q)v=#(if(eq?(q)#\#)1 0)y=#(iota(+(*(read)5)1 v))#(format #t"~{~{~a~}
~}"(map(lambda(s)(map(lambda(i)(string-ref s(modulo(+(*(char->integer z)5)i(* v
4))35)))y))(list u u u u u t t t(x" ""_"t))))
```

Usage: `$ lilypond thisfile.ly <input.in >output.out 2>/dev/null`

Comment: this is possibly the first and only time I've seen LilyPond used in code golf.

Comment: @cobbal: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433263/decision-tree-code-golf/1584216#1584216, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575096/code-golf-musical-notes/1584160#1584160, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383403/code-golf-print-the-entire-12-days-of-christmas-song-in-the-fewest-lines-of-co/1905327#1905327 (shorter than any other solution), http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Counting+adventure

Answer (score 26):

### RetroGolf - Applesoft BASIC: 236 <strike>239</strike> <strike>245</strike> <strike>249</strike> <strike>257</strike> <strike>245</strike> <strike>267</strike> <strike>285</strike>

Shown in multiple lines for readability, but should be a single line:

```
1K$="##   |   ###  #":K$="##  #"+K$+K$:
 FORI=1TO21:F$=F$+"|____":L$=L$+"|    ":NEXT:
 INPUTN$:S=MID$(N$,2,1)="#":O=(ASC(N$)-65)*5+1+S*4:L=VAL(RIGHT$(N$,2))*5+1+S:
 FORI=1TO5:?MID$(K$+K$+K$,O,L):NEXT:FORI=1TO3:?MID$(L$,O,L):NEXT:?MID$(F$,O,L)
```

Can be tested with this [Applesoft BASIC Interpreter](http://www.calormen.com/applesoft/) in Javascript or [an emulator](http://applewin.berlios.de/).

Comment: Is it possible to read both arguments on the same line, according to the specifications?

Answer (score 18):

### C# - 315

I persist to golf in C# although it's not a very terse language...

```
using C=System.Console;class P{static void L(int o,int c,string s){while(c-->0)C.Write(s[(420>>o++%5*2&3)+(91>>(o+2)/5%7&1)*3]);C.WriteLine();}static void Main(string[]a){int i=0,s=a[0].Length-1,c=int.Parse(a[1])*5+1+s,o=(a[0][0]-65+s)*5-s;while(i++<5)L(o,c,"|  ## ");while(i++<8)L(o,c,"|  |  ");L(o,c,"|__|__");}}
```

Comment: Now for the F# solution to complete the melody.

Comment: +1 for humor, -1 for corny humor, and +1 since C# and F# are concordant.

Comment: I got an System.IndexOutOfRangeException when tried to run it.

Comment: @Mendy: You have to supply command line arguments when you run it. If you run it from Visual Studio, open the properties for the project, go to the debug tab and under Start Options you can enter command line arguments. If you have compiled the code into an exe, just run it from a console window with the arguments after the program name.

Comment: +1 and I hate you. You're C# version is shorter than my F# one!

Comment: Very nice use of the --> operator.

Answer (score 16):

## Python - 164

```
k,n=raw_input().split()
m=k[1:]>""
n=int(n)*5+1
o=(ord(k[0])-65)*5+4*m
for x in["##  ###   |   ### "]*5+[n*"|    "]*3+[n*"|____"]:print((x+x[::-1][:-1])*n)[o:o+n+m]
```

Comment: Couldn't you save some characters by removing the repeated part of `t` and `u` and multiplying by 7?

Comment: @Matthew Crumley, feel free to borrow from my solution :)

Comment: @gnibbler, I'm not really a python programmer (I've played around with it some, but not extensively) so I doubt I would be able to do much with it. I didn't even know python could multiply strings like that until I saw your original solution.

Comment: @gnibbler - nice solution, would love to run it but getting a SyntaxError....
C 14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "piano.py", line 1, in ?
    k,n=input().split()
  File "<string>", line 1
    C 14
      ^

Comment: @AJ, looks like that error is from the Python3 solution. Not sure why you are getting that though

Comment: @gnibbler - because I was being dumb and copied your p3k solution and ran it in 2.6 :p

Answer (score 15):

## **Octave, 153 <strike>154</strike> <strike>155</strike> <strike>158</strike> <strike>159</strike> <strike>162</strike> <strike>172</strike> <strike>180</strike> <strike>186</strike> <strike>185</strike> <strike>188</strike> <strike>197</strike> <strike>199</strike> <strike>200</strike> <strike>206</strike> <strike>207</strike> <strike>209</strike> <strike>212</strike> <strike>214</strike> <strike>215</strike> <strike>219</strike> <strike>240</strike> <strike>244</strike> <strike>268</strike> characters**

Why use just C or C# or F# (or B or D) when you can program with a full Octave?

(wrapped every 60 chars for clarity)

```
x=5*scanf("%2c%d");for k=-8:0disp((s={[t="|   ###  ###  ","#
##   ",t" "]"|    ","|____"}{(k>-4)+!k+1})(1+mod(5*(y=x(2)>1
60)+(-y:x(3))+x(1),rows(s'))))end
```

Yes ... this solution really does compute the complex conjugate transpose of a string.

Usage: `$ octave -q thisfile.m <input.in >output.out`

Answer (score 13):

### C — 197 <del>203</del> <del>207</del> <del>216</del> <del>224</del> <del>232</del> <del>240</del> characters

```
#define S"#   |   ###  ###  ##"
main(i,j,l,h,t){char*X[]={"____|","    |",S S,S S},s[i=11];for(scanf("%s%n%d",s,&h,&l);--i>1;puts(""))for(j=t=*s%7*5+h*4;j<t+l*5+h;putchar(X[i/3][j++%(i>5?35:5)]));}
```

This equivalent **194**-character version assumes buffer overflow is fine.

```
#define S"#   |   ###  ###  ##"
i=11;main(j,l,h,t){char*X[]={"____|","    |",S S,S S},s;for(scanf("%s%n%d",&s,&h,&l);--i>1;puts(""))for(j=t=s%7*5+h*4;j<t+l*5+h;putchar(X[i/3][j++%(i>5?35:5)]));}
```

Comment: `for(j=0; j<=l*5+h; j++)` <- useless spaces, and you seem to have included them in the character count too

Answer (score 12):

## **PostScript: 239 <strike>245</strike> <strike>293</strike> <strike>312</strike> (regular); 219 <strike>224</strike> <strike>225</strike> <strike>231</strike> (ASCII85)**

```
/r{(%stdin)(r)file token pop}def[(]){mul add}/z r(:-)cvs dup length 1
sub/v exch/p r/s(|   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   )([){0 1 v p 5]{s
exch z 0 get 5]v 4]s length mod 1 getinterval print}for/
=}>>begin[[[[[/s(|    )def[[[/s(|____)def[
```

Binary version expanded through ASCII85 encoding into a 219-character program with only ASCII printable characters:

```
/(|____)/(|    )[/r/(|   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   )<~Ou%G5-$+0=Bl5@JE[d/;P,jagI?HCK@<*JGP,4<rOuSV60p8LhG*5%O8oc=a.=3b)!HsVu23Md=!IHJ_A<K->@5*j;23Md=!HoSBP&-9^09Tk/@ZkI\P"_$^I?I,S+?b-:5*?@Z>?b<9Ou$<H>EUc~>cvx
exec[
```

Usage: `$ gs -q -dNOPROMPT -dNODISPLAY -dBATCH thisfile.ps <input.in >output.out`

Comment: Love to see the less traditional languages in these contests.

Answer (score 12):

### F#: 224 <strike>225, 226, 248, 252, 270, 276, 299, 306</strike> Chars

```
let x,(/)=System.Console.ReadLine(),String.replicate
let t,p=(int x.[0]-60)%7*5,int x.[1]%2
let g s i=printf"%s"(i/((99/s).[t+4*p..t+int x.[2..]*5+5*p]+"\n"))
g"|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   "5 
g"|    "3
g"|____"1
```

I used modules of 2 to detect for a space or pound. 
' ' is 32 % 2 = 0
'#' is 35 % 2 = 1
and since my conditional returned zeros for false I just multiplied the modules result.

Used the <| operator to shave off one space char.
Used operator overloading to save another char.

original

```
let piano_long (input:string) = 
    let sharp, flat = if input.[1] = '#' then 4, 1 else 0, 0

    let note = (int input.[0] - 60) % 7
    let num = int (input.Substring 2)

    let start = note * 5 + sharp
    let stop = num * 5 + 1 + flat

    let top    = "|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |"
    let middle = "|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |"
    let bottom = "|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|"


    let mutable piano = ""

    for i in 1..5 do 
        piano <- piano + top.Substring(start, stop) + "\n"

    for i in 1..3 do 
        piano <- piano + middle.Substring(start, stop) + "\n"

    piano <- piano + bottom.Substring(start, stop)

    printf "%s\n\n" piano
```

Comment: I could shave off 46 characters if F# had a string multiply operator

Comment: A bit shorter: `let g s i=for i=1 to i do printfn"%s"(String.replicate 99 s).[t+4*p..t+int(x.[2..])*5+5*p]`

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I don't know why I couldn't find that.  I assigned it to a variable and used it twice.

Comment: Now i'm just paying the 48 char tax of .net function names.

Comment: Congrats on version 8! I am surprised how much you trimmed out.

Comment: haha, thanks!  I found an unneeded parentheses pair and saved another char.

Answer (score 11):

## **sed, 231 <strike>235</strike> <strike>234</strike> <strike>235</strike> <strike>237</strike> <strike>238</strike> <strike>244</strike> <strike>268</strike> <strike>269</strike> <strike>270</strike> <strike>276</strike> <strike>279</strike> <strike>280</strike> <strike>282</strike> <strike>287</strike> <strike>300</strike> <strike>307</strike> <strike>314</strike> <strike>329</strike> <strike>338</strike> characters**

Works for up to 99 keys. The standard piano has 52 white keys, so this should be sufficient.

```
s/.*/CDEFGABC&=0123456789-/
s/(.).=(.*)\1.*/&\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2/
s/ .?(.)=(.*)\1.*-/\2/
s/.*#/%&/
:
s/((.)(.).*\2)[#-9]/\1  \3/
t
s/[^ %CF]/###/g
s/C|F/ | /g
s/(%....)?.{25}(.*)./\2/p
p
p
p
p
s/## /|  /g
s/#[|#]/ |/g
p
p
p
y/ /_/
```

Examples:

```
$ echo C 14 | sed -rf piano.sed
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
$ echo D# 1 | sed -rf piano.sed
###   |
###   |
###   |
###   |
###   |
 |    |
 |    |
 |    |
_|____|
$ echo A 7 | sed -rf piano.sed
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ##
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
$ echo A 52 | sed -rf piano.sed
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ##
##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ##
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
```

The last example prints the standard keyboard, along with imaginary black keys on either end.

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript - 195 chars

Hey, golf is a game where you only compete against yourself right? :)

```
k=readFile(0).split(' ')
q=!k[0][1]
r=k[1]
o=''
for(x=10;x--;){p=k[0].charCodeAt(0)-65+!q
s=''
for(j=+r+1;j--;){p=++p%7
s+=x>4&&!p|p%3?'###  ':x?' |   ':'_|___'}o+=s.substring(q,r*5+2)+'\n'}print(o)
```

Solution by gnarf; ported to Rhino (with a minor fix and formatting changes) by KirarinSnow; further chipped away by gnarf; error corrected by KirarinSnow. cache `k[1]` by cwallenpoole

Usage: `$ cp input.in 0; rhino thisfile.js`

**Quick HTML Demo Version:**
[Golf Test](http://gnarf.net/golf2202897.html) -
Adds `readFile=prompt;print=function(a) {document.write("<pre>"+a);}`

Comment: Well, you also compete against the specification... and I think that you lost. ;) It doesn't even pass the test cases. It seems that it starts one off.

Comment: You only have 1 reference to b. change readFile(b) to just readFile('substring')

Comment: @wallacoloo - needed later, the part at the bottom: `s=s[b](1-q,p=s.length-3)`

Answer (score 10):

### PianoScript - 2 characters

It's a one-liner:

```
go
```

Usage:

```
PianoScript piano.ps G# 11
```

Output:

```
###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ##
###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ##
###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ##
###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ##
###  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  ###  ###   |   ###  ##
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
_|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
```

More information on the PianoScript language can be found [here](http://github.com/ogier/PianoScript).

Comment: It can be 0 characters, isn't it?

Comment: I assume in PianoScript++ you will be able to write the program in one less character.

Comment: Too bad you are not the first one who came up with this idea.

Comment: I thought domain-specific-languages were all the rage nowadays ;)

Comment: @Clueless: I love domain-specific languages (and I've golfed in a few on just this problem alone). But implementing a new one after a problem is posted is something else altogether. :p You should make PianoScript Turing-complete...

Comment: -1 for cheating, and not even coming up with a cool name for the language ;)

Comment: pianos have scores, not scripts

Answer (score 6):

## Python3 - 158

Save on `input` vs `raw_input`. Lose on `()` for `print`

```
k,n=input().split()
o=(ord(k[0])-65)*5
n=int(n)*5+1
for x in["##  ###   |   ### "]*5+[n*"|    "]*3+[n*"|____"]:print(((x+x[::-1][:-1])*n)[o+3*len(k[1:]):o+n])
```

Answer (score 5):

**F#: 355 significant chars**

All on one line:

```
let[|x;y|]=System.Console.ReadLine().Split([|' '|])in[for i in 1..9->let r (a:string) b j (s:string)=s.Replace(a,if i>j then b else a)in((String.replicate(int y+1)"23012123012121").Substring(int(x.[0])-65,int y*2+x.Length).Replace("0","|   ")|>r"1""#"0|>r"2""##  "0|>r"3"" "0).TrimEnd()|>r"###"" | "5|>r"##""| "5|>r" ""_"8]|>String.concat"\n"|>printfn "%s"
```

Expanded:

```
let piano() =
    let[|x;y|]=System.Console.ReadLine().Split([|' '|])in
    [for i in 1..9->
        let r (a:string) b j (s:string) = s.Replace(a,if i>j then b else a) in
        ((String.replicate (int y+1) "23012123012121")
            .Substring(int(x.[0])-65,int y*2+x.Length).Replace("0","|   ")
            |> r "1" "#" 0
            |> r "2" "##  " 0
            |> r "3" " " 0)
            .TrimEnd()|> r "###" " | " 5|> r "##" "| " 5|> r " " "_" 8]
    |> String.concat "\n"
    |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: @Brian, please get the team to implement `gets` or equivalent, we would save 22 characters!

Comment: I find that when golfing recursion is a good way to remove type annotations.

Answer (score 3):

### SETL

165 characters; Translation of gribblers Python solution.

```
get(l);[k,n]:=split(l);o:=(abs k(1)-65)*5;n:=1+5*val n;(for x in['##  ###   |   ### ']*5+[n*'|    ']*3+[n*'|____'])print(((x+reverse x(2..))*n)(o+4*#k-3..o+n));end;
```

Answer (score 3):

### D2 (templates): 331 <del>370</del> <del>400</del> + 17 characters

(based on the Ruby solution.)

Compressed:

```
template J(alias T,int b,int e,r...){static if(e)enum J=T!(b,r)~J!(T,b+1,e-1,r);else enum J="";}template K(int i,int t){enum K=t>7?"_|___":t<5&&3&i%7?"###  ":" |   ";}template R(int t,int s,int l,int h){enum R=J!(K,s-h,l,t)[h..$-3]~"\n";}template M(alias k){enum M=J!(R,0,9,k[0]+1,k[$-2]>32?k[$-1]+10*k[$-2]-527:k[$-1]-47,k[0]&1);}
```

Explained:

```
/**
    Macros:
        D = <tt>$0</tt>
 */
 ;

/**
    $(D_PSYMBOL J) (short for "join") will evaluate $(D T!(i,r)) for
    $(D_PARAM i) in $(D [b..b+e]). Then, these compile-time strings will be
    concatenated.
 */
template J(alias T,int b,int e,r...){
    static if(e)
        enum J=T!(b,r)~J!(T,b+1,e-1,r);
    else
        enum J="";
}

/**
    $(D_PSYMBOL K) (short for "key") will generate 5 characters as a row of
    key $(D_PARAM i) at row $(D_PARAM t).
 */
template K(int i,int t){
    enum K=t>7?"_|___":t<5&&3&i%7?"###  ":" |   ";
}

/**
    $(D_PSYMBOL R) (short for "row") will generate the keyboard at row
    $(D_PARAM t), from key $(D_PARAM s) and sharpness $(D_PARAM h) with a
    length of $(D_PARAM l) keys.
 */
template R(int t,int s,int l,int h){
    enum R=J!(K,s-h,l,t)[h..$-3]~"\n";
}

/**
    $(D_PSYMBOL M) (short for "main") results in the whole keyboard as a string.

    Example:
    -----
    pragma(msg,M!("C 14"));
    pragma(msg,M!("D# 1"));
    pragma(msg,M!("A 7"));
    -----
 */
template M(alias k){
    enum M=J!(R,0,9,k[0]+1,k[$-2]>32?k[$-1]+10*k[$-2]-527:k[$-1]-47,k[0]&1);
}
```

Since we can't pass parameters from `dmd` the input must be done in the code. Supports only up to 99 keys.

Comment: Can you make the input a single string? Part of the challenge is parsing the line into a note, an optional sharp, and a duration. The parsing itself can take quite a few characters in some languages...

Answer (score 2):

Haskell: <s>212</s> <s>211</s> 208 characters

```
a="  |  "
b=" ### "
d=concat.cycle
e=d[b,b,a,b,b,a,b]
f=d[a]
t x s m n=map(take(5*read s+m).drop(5*length['@'..x]-n))[e,e,e,e,e,f,f,f,d["__|__"]]
u(x:'#':s)=t x s 2 4 
u(x:s)=t x s 1 8
main=interact$unlines.u
```

It still assumes ascii-compatible letters (specifically, the sequence "@ABCDEFG"), but no longer requires Char.ord

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - 113 chars

Runs with command line arguments

```
$ ruby piano.rb A 7

k,c=$*
9.times{|x|puts (((b=x<8?'  |  ':'__|__')+(a=x<5?' ### ':b)*3+b+a*2)*j=k[0]*5-2+4*s=k.size)[j,c.to_i*5+s]}
```

**Ruby - 118 chars**

```
k,c=$*
9.times{|x|puts (((b=x<8?'  |  ':'__|__')+(a=x<5?' ### ':b)*3+b+a*2)*j=2+k[0]*5+4*s=k.size-1)[j..c.to_i*5+s+j]}
```

Answer (score 2):

**PHP - 208 chars**

```
<?$e=45*substr($a=PIANO,2+$d=!($a[1]^~ì))+9+$d*45;$j=9*$c=4*$d;for($b=ord($a[0])-65,--$c;$j<$e;$f[$i=$j++%9].=($c=($c+!$i)%5)%4<2&$i>3&$b%3!=2?Ü:($c?$i?ß: :))$j%45-36?:$b=++$b%7;for(;$a=$f[$i--];)echo~$a,~õ;
```

Shall have to be improved.

The input has to be delivered in the constant named PIANO.

Answer (score 1):

### **F# <strike>414</strike> <strike>386</strike> 372** significant characters:

```
//wins me 2 characters
open System

//String.replicate, didn't know this existed before reading Juliet
let r=String.replicate  

//print s n times, each time on a newline
let P n s=printf"%s"(r n (s+"\n"))  

//define top rows
let t="##  ###   |   ###  ###   |   ###  #" 

//middle and bottom rows can be defined using 'r'
let m,b=r 7"|    ",r 7"|____" 

//pick of chars from O to n+O from string, wrap round if we go beyond s.Length
let L(s:string)O n=String([|5*O..5*(n+O)|]|>Array.map(fun i->s.[i%35]))

//match input string into two halves
let[|k;n|]=Console.ReadLine().Split([|' '|])

//work out start pos and length (in chars, not keys)
let O,N=
 let K=int k.[0]-65                    //'A'=65, this is why t starts at A
 if k.[0]='#'then(K+3,int n+2)else(K,int n) 

//Print 5 top rows, 3 middle rows and the bottom row
P 5(L t O N)
P 3(L m O N)
P 1(L b O N)
```

Oh, and one bonus, this script will actually handle "F# 372" correctly - I won't annoy you by pasting it here though...

*System.Console.ReadLine() is such a bummer...*